# Python-Pygame: how to move multiple full object

Tags: python, pygame, drawing

I have drawn a snowman. But I need to make 3 of them, and not by changing their coordinates 1 by 1. I thought maybe I define 1 value in ever location and then it may be able to move it towards x axis.
 Current:

```
i= 0
import pygame, sys 
pygame.init() # Käivitame Pygame'i
ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 800]) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Snowmen") 

ekraan.fill([0, 0, 250])
def snowman():
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400, 200], 60, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400, 300], 75, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400, 450], 110, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [380, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [420, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [350, 110, 100, 50], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [330, 155, 140, 5], 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 440], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 480], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 400], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 360], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 320], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400, 280], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(ekraan, [255,165,0], [[400, 205], [400, 195],[450, 200]], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [450, 300], [505, 260], 8)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [500, 190], [500, 550], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498, 190], [480, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498, 190], [485, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498, 190], [490, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500, 190], [495, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500, 190], [500, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500, 190], [505, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502, 190], [510, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502, 190], [515, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502, 190], [520, 142], 2)

while i < 3:
    i+=1
    snowman(k*40)  

pygame.display.flip() # Näitame akent

running = True # Muutuja "running" väärtustamine
while running: #Tsükli käivitamine kui muutuja on tõene
    for i in pygame.event.get(): # Kuulame programmi tööd
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT: # Kui vajutame akna sulgemise nuppu
            running = False # Muudame muutuja väärtuse vääraks
pygame.quit() # Sulgeme programmi akna
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass a value to a function? You need to add a parameter to the function definition, for example `def snowman(x):`, then you'll have the `k*40` value from the while loop (btw `k` is not defined anywhere) available inside the function and can add it to the x-positions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create function with argument - ie. `offset` - and use this value with all `x` parameters

```
def snowman(offset):
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 200], 60, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 300], 75, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 450], 110, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [380+offset, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [420+offset, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [350+offset, 110, 100, 50], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [330+offset, 155, 140, 5], 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 440], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 480], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 400], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 360], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 320], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 280], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(ekraan, [255,165,0], [[400+offset, 205], [400+offset, 195],[450+offset, 200]], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [450+offset, 300], [505+offset, 260], 8)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [500+offset, 190], [500+offset, 550], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [480+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [485+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [490+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [495+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [500+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [505+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [510+offset, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [515+offset, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [520+offset, 142], 2)
```

And then you can run it with different values

```
for k in range(-1, 2):
    snowman(k*250)
```

---

Full working code

```
# all imports at the top !!!
import pygame
import sys 

# --- functions ---

def snowman(offset):
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 200], 60, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 300], 75, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [400+offset, 450], 110, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [380+offset, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0, 0, 0], [420+offset, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [350+offset, 110, 100, 50], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(ekraan, [78, 71, 71], [330+offset, 155, 140, 5], 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 440], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 480], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 400], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 360], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 320], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(ekraan, [0,0,0], [400+offset, 280], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(ekraan, [255,165,0], [[400+offset, 205], [400+offset, 195],[450+offset, 200]], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [450+offset, 300], [505+offset, 260], 8)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [139, 69, 19], [500+offset, 190], [500+offset, 550], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [480+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [485+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [498+offset, 190], [490+offset, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [495+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [500+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [500+offset, 190], [505+offset, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [510+offset, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [515+offset, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(ekraan, [255, 250, 250], [502+offset, 190], [520+offset, 142], 2)

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 800]) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Snowmen") 

# - draw -

ekraan.fill([0, 0, 250])

for k in range(-1, 2):
    snowman(k*250)  

pygame.display.flip()

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    clock.tick(5) # slow down to 5 FPS so it will use less CPU power.

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

---

There is also other method.

You create `Surface` and draw on it and later you `blit` this surface in three different places.

```
# all import at the top !!!
import pygame
import sys 

# --- functions ---

def create_snowman():
    # create surface
    image = pygame.Surface((300, 600)).convert_alpha()

    # fill with transparent background [x,x,x,0]
    image.fill([0, 0, 0, 0])

    # draw on surface
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [255, 250, 250], [150, 200], 60, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [255, 250, 250], [150, 300], 75, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [255, 250, 250], [150, 450], 110, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0, 0, 0], [130, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0, 0, 0], [170, 175], 12, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(image, [78, 71, 71], [100, 110, 100, 50], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(image, [78, 71, 71], [100, 155, 140, 5], 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 440], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 480], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 400], 9, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 360], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 320], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, [0,0,0], [150, 280], 8, 0)
    pygame.draw.polygon(image, [255,165,0], [[150, 205], [150, 195],[200, 200]], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [139, 69, 19], [200, 300], [255, 260], 8)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [139, 69, 19], [250, 190], [250, 550], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [248, 190], [230, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [248, 190], [235, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [248, 190], [240, 138], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [250, 190], [245, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [250, 190], [250, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [250, 190], [255, 140], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [252, 190], [260, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [252, 190], [265, 142], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(image, [255, 250, 250], [252, 190], [270, 142], 2)

    return image

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
ekraan = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 800]) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Snowmen") 

# - draw -

# get image and rect
snowman_image = create_snowman()
snowman_rect = snowman_image.get_rect()

ekraan.fill([0, 0, 250])

# blit image on screen
for k in range(0, 3):
    snowman_rect.x = k*250
    ekraan.blit(snowman_image, snowman_rect)

pygame.display.flip()

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    clock.tick(5) # slow down to 5 FPS so it will use less CPU power.

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```